# dynamic variable.optiones.selected

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm new here in this Forum so this is my first question.
If I do something wrong just say it.
But now my Question: I've got a multiple select in a html file which values I save in a Database. When the site is loaded again I would like to select the select options that were selected before automaticly. For this I need something like this:

```
<select multiple id="a">
    <option>tomato</option>
</select>
<select multiple id="b">
    <option>apple</option>
</select>
<select multiple id="c">
    <option>orange</option>
</select>
<select multiple id="d">
    <option>cake</option>
</select>

<script>
var ids = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
for(i=0, i < 4, i++){
    var id = ids[i];
    id.options[0].selected = true;
}
</script>
```

This is what I tried (on the web page the selects have more then one option). I've done also research in the internet, but I was not able to find good results.
The problem is the dynamic variable it's interpreted like it's a id of an html object by the compiler but it should be interpreted like a variable. I only need the right syntax.
But I couldn't get it to work because there is an error whit the dyanamic variable. How can I do this right, that it works?

Comment: Do learn basics of the programming before jumping into _sea_.. As you are gonna get many big fishes later on....

Comment: If this are Basics of programming why don't you answer my question then?

Comment: Well, Your question does not qualify as an valid SO question. You must share what efforts you have taken to achieve what you want. Also [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Kindly do not teach me what to do and what not to do.. It is totally my preference...

Comment: So I edited the post. I think now it's better.

Comment: Which option you want to be selected ?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot that but now it's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I done a lot o research again and now I done it this way:

```
document.getElementById(id).options[0].selected = true;
```